# Force an error in SPSS Syntax when condition is met

Tags: syntax, error-handling, try-catch, spss

I'm doing a check in my syntax to see if all of the string fields have values. This looks something like this:

```
IF(STRING ~= "").
```

Now, instead of filtering or computing a variable, I would like to force an error if there are fields with no values. I'm running a lot of these scripts and I don't want to keep checking the datasets manually. Instead, I just want to receive an error and stop execution.

Is this possible in SPSS Syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can efficiently count the blanks in your string variables with COUNT:

COUNT blanks = A B C(" ").

where you list the string variables to be checked.  So if the sum of blanks is > 0, you want the error to be raised.  First aggregate to a new dataset and activate it:

DATASET DECLARE sum.
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE=sum /count=sum(blanks).

The hard part is getting the job to stop when the blank count is greater than 0.  You can put the job in a syntax file and run it using INSERT with ERROR=STOP, or you can run it as a production job via Utilities or via the -production flag on the command line of an spj (production facility) job.

Here is how to generate an error on a condition.

```
DATASET ACTIVATE sum.
begin program.
import spssdata

curs = spssdata.Spssdata()
count = curs.fetchone()
curs.CClose()

if count[0] > 0:
    spss.Submit("blank values exist")
end program.
DATASET CLOSE sum.
```

This code reads the aggregate file and if the blank count is positive issues an invalid command causing an error, which stops the job.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into it